# Low-reputation employees should not do moderation activities that require being familiar with the site

Tags: discussion, privileges

Some employees are diamond users and therefore have full privileges on the site. I think they should not be doing moderation activities that require being familiar with the site, like voting to close/reopen, until they would normally earn those privileges. The reason being they are more likely to get it wrong and have a binding vote.

Example: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5400163/revisions) was incorrectly reopened by two users and a diamond employee with ~150 reputation at the time.

Comment: How do you know Jaydles isn't secretly Jon Skeet?

Comment: That question is still sitting there open a year later. How "incorrect" was that really?

Comment: @deceze Are you saying it should stay open? It's a textbook example of being too broad and opinion based.

Comment: That was a somewhat rhetorical question. The fact is, nobody has disputed the reopening so far.

Comment: And while we do have a letter of the law, the main thing we want to be is *helpful*. And that question is *hugely* popular, which sometimes trumps strict guidelines.

Comment: Yeah, good old "be popular so rules stop applying to you" (aka ad populatum) problem. Apparently nobody learned the problem with popularity... PHP and Justin Bieber are good because they are popular.

Comment: Anyone who listens to the stuff he says/writes knows that Jaydles isn't "unfamiliar with the site." Being familiar with the community dynamics of SO/SE is his *job*. He's just not from a tech background so he's not in the position to amass lots of reputation on SO. I agree that wasn't an appropriate reopening, but I'll bet there's a background story there, plus it's hardly enough to derive from it that low-rep employees are defacing the site with ill-advised actions

Comment: I'm sure there is a backstory. Most likely, someone emailed the team (or tweeted or Facebooked or however people rant these days) and complained about the question being closed. So a team member, like Jaydles, looked at the question, decided it seemed reasonable, and reopened it. I suppose this is okay, as long as the community maintains the power to override such decisions.

Comment: @CodyGray backstory is pretty simple, I wrote about this in [comment to Tim's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341663/low-reputation-employees-should-not-do-moderation-activities-that-require-being#comment433345_341672 "'SE team has some script that notifies them when high views old questions get closed. Sometimes they reopen questions reported by the script for reasons that look opaque for site regulars. At SE.SE (aka Programmers) another member of SE team attempted reopening such questions at least twice...'")

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They're less likely to get it wrong because they typically consult the *entire* community team prior to doing something, and receive additional training from us as we give them the diamond.

It's their *job* to do this stuff, we trust them to do it, and they're just as accountable as any other elected or appointed moderator if they make a mistake. Additionally, those mistakes are just as easily fixed; their status as an employee doesn't give them abilities beyond what an elected moderator would have.

People working on product teams need to be able to close questions (most importantly as duplicates) as they fix bugs, implement features, etc. They also need to be able to apply status tags - we can't wait for them to have the rep to edit in order to do that.

If you see one of us screw up, *just say something* - we'll fix it and that person will learn from it. But we're talking about something that very, very rarely happens (mostly because the community team is so frequently consulted)

If we hire a product manager that's in charge of a big new feature, we want them working on that feature, with all of the tools that they need to do their job. Being able to cast binding votes is quite often one of those jobs. If you see a mistake, just point it out, we'll fix it or explain why it wasn't a mistake.

---

Update (RE: Popular closed questions)

This was a procedural thing that wasn't as optimal as it should be. We have alerts that get sent to an email forwarder whenever a question that has considerable views / votes / etc is closed by the community. It's not our job to rubber-stamp reopen them, but just to review to make sure that a simple edit wouldn't fix what was wrong, and make sure the closing made sense.

This list went to *everyone*, and one couldn't be sure if someone even saw the alert. We now direct them to the CMs in charge of watching that particular site, who are generally better at spotting the problematic parts (and either fixing the question so it's fine to reopen, or just leaving it closed and possibly raising a discussion about scope).

Comment: I'm not saying you should take away their ability to do those things, as indeed that would complicate things between Main and Meta. Just that they shouldn't. However, if they usually consult the community team, then I agree this should be a rare occurrence. I didn't try to find other cases, just bumped into this one.

Comment: Just for the record, would it be possible to find out what happened in this particular case?

Comment: @Stijn SE team has some script that notifies them when high views old questions get closed. Sometimes they reopen questions reported by the script for reasons that look opaque for site regulars. At SE.SE (aka Programmers) another member of SE team attempted reopening such questions at least twice, see [Why was 'How can I deal with the cargo-cult programming attitude?' reopened?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7289/31260) and [Why was “Why aren't young programmers interested in mainframes?” re-opened?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7649/31260)

Comment: Thanks for adding the update; that addressed my concerns that this answer was a bit too generalized and didn't actually deal with the issue presented in the question. Directing the information to the persons most familiar with the site just makes good sense, and definitely seems like a scalability improvement.

Comment: @CodyGray Not yet a perfect system, far from it, but we're still doing a lot of work on it. Hard to keep up on hundreds of sites without basically assigning certain people to pay extra attention to certain ones, while still keeping our ability for any CM to jump into anything. Some serious human scalability stuff for sure :)

Comment: FWIW, the rules that generate team notifications are nearly the same as [the ones that push popular questions into the reopen queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue/196078#196078), but with (much) higher thresholds for votes / views. As a result, we don't see questions until folks within the community have had a chance to consider / discuss / revise them first; the usual outcome *isn't* reopening (only in about 5% of cases), but rather a view into what sorts of questions are potential stumbling blocks for searchers.